# Buscar valores entre duas datas no SQLIte

Tags: sqlite

Como posso encontrar os registros em duas datas no banco **SQLite**?

No mysql sei que é através do  `BETWEEN`, mas não sei como faz no SQLIte.

Comment: No *SQLite* é `BETWEEN` https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Answer (score 1):

O SQLite utiliza o BETWEEN como dito no comentário, segue exemplo:

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/974c2/2):

```
SELECT * FROM Pessoa WHERE Data BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2015-01-01'
```

Obs.: Se você tentou com `BETWEEN` e não conseguiu o problema pode estar no formato da data, o SQLite espera que a data esteja em um formato `YYYY-MM-DD`, pode ser que ele esteja tratando sua busca como `string`.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187379/7558069

Answer (score -3):

Basta colocar .AsDate := StrToDate(Ndata);
a data pode estar em DD/MM/AA mesmo.
Segue código:

DmS.Qsq4.Close;

Dms.Qsq4.SQL.Clear;
Dms.Qsq4.SQL.Add(Sql);

Dms.Qsq4.Parambyname('DATAINI').AsDate := StrToDate(Ndataini);

Dms.Qsq4.Parambyname('DATAFIN').AsDate := StrToDate(Ndatafin);

Dms.Qsq4.Open;

Dms.Qsq4.first;

Comment: Obrigado, resolvido!